# Exclude main project .h file in subproject

Tags: ios, xcode, header, subproject

I have an xcode project importing a subproject . **I put both in a same folder**.

Like this :

> /app/MainProject
>       /app/folder/SubProject

There is some same-name file in both project .Example , both project
have "test.h" file

When i run the app, SubProject will compile "test.h" file from main
project instead of it's own "test.h" file .

So how i cant exclude header file in MainProject from my SubProject ?

**Thank you**

Comment: when i run SubProject alone , it compile completety normal .

Comment: But when imported and copy it in MainProject , it ll take MainProject header file instead (if they have same name)

Comment: Don't post updates as comments. Edit your question with all relevant details.